# Removing the NA element from the legend for extra data element in facets

Tags: r, ggplot2

In general I know that I can use `breaks` in my `scale_color_manual` command to remove a specific label. But for some reason this doesn't work in my case and I don't see the error. If I try to set the breaks (uncommenting the breaks line) it removes the whole legend.

Did I overlook something? Is it maybe it is not the overall data frame? The Thing is that I want to have thresholds in only one of the facets.

```
library(ggplot2)
threshold <- log2(c(1.5,2))
ggplot() +
  geom_hline(data=data.frame(category=c('contains virus IDs', 
                                        rep('enriched',4)),
                             threshold=c(NA, threshold, -threshold),
                             color=c(NA, rep(2^threshold, 2))),
             aes(yintercept=threshold, color=as.factor(color)), 
             na.rm=TRUE) +
  scale_color_manual('threshold', 
                     values=c(`2`='red', `1.5`='orange')
                     # , breaks=c(`2`='2 fold', `1.5`='1.5 fold')
                     ) +
  facet_grid(~ category, scales='free_x', space='free_x')
```

Comment: Simple workaround is just to wrap your data.frame with `na.omit`.

Comment: @PoGibas Good point, in my original Data I have also a category where I don't want to add lines, but I do not need to add Gas, thats good to know. But I still can't overwrite the numbers to `2 fold` for example... I know I can do this when creating the `color` column in the `data.frame` but I am still wondering what the issue is.

Comment: What about `labels=c(\`2\`='2 fold', \`1.5\`='1.5 fold')` instead of `breaks`?

Comment: ahhhhhhh!!! :-) But why not `breaks`? I thought I do this with the breaks...

Comment: Ahhh, now I got it, within `breaks` I am not allowed to overwrite the labels. so `breaks=c(2,1.5)` would do what I expected. And adding `labels` will overwrite the labels! Perfect thanks